# COM Exception with c# webbrowser while clicking an event

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control, comexception

I'm using C# Webbrowser to navigate a site and click some links. So When a page loads it's supposed to raise an onclick event for an anchor. Also, using InvokeMethod("click") hasn't ever worked for me.

```
private void StartGetDetails(HtmlElementCollection links)
    {
        if (csrLinks.Count > 0)
        {
            HtmlElement csr = csrLinks.First();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            csr.RaiseEvent("onclick");
            csrLinks.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error at csr.RaiseEvent("onclick"):

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Any help would be appreciated, nothing I found googling around seemed helpful.

Comment: What is `csrLinks`, why don't you use `links`? Any **real** code to post?

Comment: Oops, my apologies, csrLinks is a global List<HtmlElement>. Basically, I have a list of anchors of ids in an html table, I get the links into a list, go in each object, parse and leave. Once I'm back at the list I go into the next link. The code works otherwise and only fails here.

Comment: What version of Windows is this?

Comment: It's Windows 7, I was using IE11, downgraded to IE9 now.

Comment: Are you calling `StartGetDetails` on the *same* thread where the `WebBrowser` was created? I.e., the main UI thread?

Comment: Yes, the WebBrowser and all its code are running on the same thread. This program is trying to crawl a ticketing software. I'm writing this mostly event-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that I've fixed the problem. The problem was that the HtmlElement I was trying to raise onclick for did not have an onclick method, or was null. However, WebBrowser was instead sending this exception rather than a NullReference exception.